# Can this formula be simplified?

Tags: statistics

Math isn't my forte but to achieve some tasks I had to jump in to some extensive mathematical usage.

In short, I have to develop an on-call sheet roster, where the employees who take earlier slots participating gets paid comparatively less bonus amount than those who take the late in the day slots, from a pre-decided team budget. A peak margin is decided every week depending over the workload that is expected.

I have been able to express my requirement in form of a formula and it works fine but I just think that its necessarily complicated and could be have done in a simpler way.

`=[total team budget]-([total team budget]*([peak margin]*100/100-[slot])/100)`

an example sheet:

```
Slot (n)    payment for the nth slot employee
1       $9,100.0
2 $9,200.0
3       $9,300.0
4 $9,400.0
5       $9,500.0
6 $9,600.0
7       $9,700.0
8 $9,800.0
9       $9,900.0
10 $10,000.0
    
total team budget   $10,000.0
peak hike $10.0
```

Am I missing something, is there a way I can simplify (beautify) my formula expression to achieve the similar results, probably by using some advanced functions?

TIA!

Comment: You mean "peak margin". It's an important concept to spell correctly.

Comment: i am sorry, it was my mistake

Comment: I'm also wondering whether there's a mistake in the formula, because [peak margin] * 100 / 100 - [slot] simplifies down to [peak margin] - [slot]. Did you mean [peak margin] * 100 / (100 - [slot]) or something?

Comment: Sorry to say, but this formula is extremely simple already. Anyway, the $100/100$ ratio has no reason to be there and you can factor out TTB, but this makes little difference.

Comment: IMO it was a bit unfair to mark this question down, whoever did that, so I marked it up, because it's a fair question.